# order_cancel_after event doesn't gives the total number of canceled orders in magento 2

Tags: magento2, magento2.3

I am trying to achieve total number of canceled order when any of the placed order has been canceled by admin area. The problem i am facing that i am getting wrong number of canceled order by difference of 1. It means the order which has been just canceled in this event (order_cancel_after) is not being calculated.

Here is the code below. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**In etc/adminhtml/events.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">    
    <event name="order_cancel_after">
        <observer name="order_cancel_placed_after" instance="My\MyModule\Observer\SalesOrderCancelAfter"/>
    </event>
</config>
```

In Observer/SalesOrderCancelAfter.php

```
<?php

namespace My\MyModule\Observer;

use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Event\Observer;
use Magento\Sales\Model\Order;
use My\MyModule\Helper\Data;

class SalesOrderCancelAfter implements ObserverInterface
{

    protected $order;

    protected $helperData;


    public function __construct(
        Order $order,
        Data $helperData
    )
    {
        $this->order = $order;
        $this->helperData = $helperData;
    }

    public function execute(Observer $observer)
    {
        $order = $observer->getEvent()->getOrder();
        $customerEmail = $order->getCustomerEmail();

        /* To get the total number of canceled orders */
        $ordercollection  = $this->order->getCollection()
            ->addAttributeToFilter('customer_email', $customerEmail)
            ->addFieldToFilter('status', array('in' => array('canceled')));
        $totalcancelorder = $ordercollection->getSize();        
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because the order that is in the cancelation process is not yet saved to the DB, so getting a collection will not include your order because the status in the database is not cancelled.

The easiest solution is manually add your order:

```
        /* To get the total number of canceled orders */
    $ordercollection  = $this->order->getCollection()
        ->addAttributeToFilter('customer_email', $customerEmail)
        ->addFieldToFilter('status', array('in' => array('canceled')));
    $totalcancelorder = $ordercollection->getSize();   

    if ($observer->getEvent()->getOrder()->getStatus() == 'canceled') {
        totalcancelorder++;
    }
```

or just add 1. `$totalcancelorder = $ordercollection->getSize() + 1;` because the status will always be 'cancelled' because that's how the event works.

Comment: Thanks for your input. Seems correct to me. But i have a doubt here, should i use this
if ($observer->getEvent()->getOrder() == 'canceled') 
or this 
if ($observer->getOrder() == 'canceled')

Comment: `getOrder() == 'canceled'` is 100% wrong. calling getEvent() before getOrder() is correct! is have written my code without testing. i've changed my answer. thanks for your feedback

Comment: Thanks for your valuable investigate. I will accept this answer.